# Is it possible to direct subdomain to another file in the server without the file path?

Tags: .htaccess, dns

I have a server e.g. 123.123.123.123 and I have /index.html and /login.php files in it, amongst others.

Is it possible to have www.mydomain.com pointing to 123.123.123.123/index.html
but login.mydomain.com pointing to 123.123.123.123/login.php automatically?

currently our setup has login.mydomain.com with the A record pointing to 123.123.123.123, but the URL bar will show login.mydomain.com/login.php. What we want is "login.mydomain.com" only to be shown on the URL bar.

Is this possible? Thanks in advance.

Comment: URL bar will usually show whatever user types there, though you can change that with redirect. Do you really want (when user adds /login.php manually) it to disappear? Also, what currently happens if user tries www.mydomain.com? Is there any .htaccess already present? Do you have access to Apache .conf files or you can only use .htaccess?

Comment: I can only use .htaccess and there is one already present, but it's only a few lines of simple url renaming. I don't need the /login.php to disappear if the user types login.mydomain.com/login.php, but currently if we type login.mydomain.com, it routes to 123.123.123.123 (from the DNS CNAME). but the index.html here is another page. So in order to achieve the result, we have a .htaccess that rewrites login.mydomain.com to the file, that looks something like this: RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?login\.mydomain\.com.$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http\:\/\/www\.mydomain\.com\./s_login$1